# how to extract data from json. other answers here did not work for me

Tags: python, json

i want to extract Mac_Address from this json in python. anyone can help ?

```
{"list":
    [{
       "Group_Devices_id":3,
       "User_Id":19,
       "Mac_Address":" fe80::f17a:4a64:7192:ed68%2 ",
       "Master_Device":"T"
    }],
    "success":true}
```

Comment: The doc could : https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#basic-usage

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing values from a JSON file using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559/parsing-values-from-a-json-file-using-python)

Comment: Use python json libraray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- Import json
- data = json.loads('{"list": [{ "Group_Devices_id":3, "User_Id":19,
   "Mac_Address":" fe80::f17a:4a64:7192:ed68%2 ", "Master_Device":"T"
   }], "success":true}')
- data['list'][0]['Mac_Address']

Desc : Import json libraray, then load your data. then access any elements.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
data = json.loads('{"list": [{ "Group_Devices_id":3, "User_Id":19,
       "Mac_Address":" fe80::f17a:4a64:7192:ed68%2 ", "Master_Device":"T"
       }], "success":true}'

for item in data["list"]:
   print item["Mac_Address"]
```

1) Load data

2) Assume you need to get Mac_Address from lots of data of list,
   then use "for...in.." to process

Comment: Please include some explanation around your answer as to why it solves the OP's original question. This may help - [answer]